# Positions of objects in the scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

My hierarchy of game objects is as follow.

```
Display(Scene)
    Model(-4.708, 1.55, 14.4277)
       Pass(4.7080, -1.5, -14.42)
         handle(-0.0236,0.65690,0.149)
           shaft(5.34,-1.0225,-0.1489)
              head(-7.0912,-9.62,-0.5231)​
    ball(0,0,0)
```

We can see Model and its coordinate on the image. Ball has position (0,0,0), but why it is located at the base of the Model?

How can I locate ball just beside the head?

[image]

Comment: I am guessing this model is created in another 3d software, It is **mostly** because of , while modeling the object, they are ignoring the origin point in that program. so the (0,0,0) in unity is diffenent than expected. Try importing the model in a 3d modeling software and adjust the origin there. At least that what was happened to me and thats how i solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the origin point of one or more of the models is at off.

You can adjust this in 3d modelling software, or by making an empty game object inside unity and making your object a child of that object, then using the empty game object as the new origin point, you can adjust the positions of the child objects you assign to it.

Comment: Thanks. I like to make the positioning of the ball near the club head. So that when the club's collider collides with ball's collider and the ball flies. Then the club type is changed so that position of the ball can't be fixed. I need to change position of the ball in the script according to the position of the head. How can I position the ball near to club head in the program?

Comment: You can generally speaking move objects through their Transform. A transform has the position, scale and rotation of an object. But I'm not sure i understand why you wish to change the balls position to be closer to the head. Do you mean you wish to use the force from the club head to move the ball?